# Hard drive serial number check

Tags: php, echo

If you running this script on localhost is give you the hard drive serial number.
My hard drive serial number is: CC17-BEBF

```
<?php
function GetVolumeLabel($drive) {
if (preg_match('#Volume Serial Number is (.*)\n#i', shell_exec('dir '.$drive.':'), $m)) {
$volname = ' ('.$m[1].')';
} else {
$volname = '';
}
return $volname;
}
$serial = str_replace("(","",str_replace(")","",GetVolumeLabel("c")));

echo $serial;
?>
```

Result is: **CC17-BEBF**

If I'm running

```
<?php
if ($serial == 'CC17-BEBF') {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
?>
```

Result is: **false**

Why?

Comment: Using `$serial = 'CC17-BEBF';
if ($serial == 'CC17-BEBF') {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}` came out true. So, the problem may lie in your function.

Comment: Is the second snippet in the same file as the first one, or a different one?

Comment: I can't use $serial = 'CC17-BEBF';

Comment: Perhaps there is whitespace that you cannot see when printing `$serial`. You should `echo "[$serial]"` or similar to see if this is the case. If so, you should [`trim`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.trim.php) it before returning.

Comment: Also, consider using proper indentation so your code is readable.

Comment: If you look carefully, there's a whitespace before the opening parenthesis. `$volname = ' ('.$m[1].')';`

Comment: I don't know how. Can you give me a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Jonathan provided you with a link to it, being http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.trim.php and there are examples in there that you can base yourself on.

Comment: Is working now. So simple. I searched for hours. Thanks  **pikachu0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add space bar before serial:

```
if ($serial == " CC17-BEBF") {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Or add `trim()` function when declare `$serial`:

```
$serial = trim(str_replace("(","",str_replace(")","",GetVolumeLabel("c"))));
```

To prevent additional white space.